# custom chapter title

Tags: titles, chapters

I'm using a template and it displays the chapter title like this picture
(a big number for the chapter and the title of the chapter)
I need it to display the word "chapter" too
any idea how to do it??
thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add a small but complete, compilable document to your question that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: The word "Chapter" is added by default. Moral: Do not use templates as far as possible. Start by a standard `book`, `scrbook` or  `memoir` and add code to the preamble only if you know what it is for. If you really need some feature of the template, try to analyze how is done and reuse only the relevant code in your own document.